# Bro IDS Signature file error

Tags: bash, intrusion-detection, bro, zeek

I am trying to run bro in my bash terminal. I have got a duplicate `local.bro` file which i renamed as `localv2.bro`, and put it in my working directory `/home/bibin`, so its not in default path. I am just trying to do a simple signature match, therefore i have created a `signature.sig` file in the directory. In my `localv2.bro` file i have tried using both ways:

```
@load-sigs ./signature
```

And

```
redef signature_files += "signature.sig
```

The `signature.sig` file has the [signature my-first-sig](https://www.bro.org/sphinx/frameworks/signatures.html#id4) example from bro.org site.

In the terminal when i try to execute this command:

```
bro -r traffic.pcap localv2.bro
```

I get an error message saying:

```
line 27: unrecognized character -
```

I have also tried doing it in a different route:

```
bro -r traffic.pcap -s signature.sig
```

This also gives me the same unrecognized character error.

Am i doing something wrong, please can you guide me to a solution ?

Comment: New update: bro -r traffic.pcap localvs.bro    I get an error "Failed to find file associated with @load-sigs ./signature"   Does this mean it cant find the path of the signature.sig file?

Comment: Make sure you format your code snippets as code, so your question is more clear. You might also post the entire `localv2.bro` file, instead of just a couple of lines from it. That way people can see exactly what's going on.

Comment: @ZacDelventhal Thanks for the suggested edit. Please also make sure to remove common boilerplate like "thanks", "any help pls" etc in future edits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback! i will be careful next time :)